# Beautiful Soup Classic Confusion

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

Working with Python and Beautifulsoup.  A bit new to CSS markup, so I know I'm making some beginner mistakes, a specific example would go a long way in helping me understand.

I'm trying to scrape a page for links, but only certain links.

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoXTx.png)

```
links = soup.find_all("a", class_="details-title")
```

Comment: Is that `css markup` or `html markup` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have will search for links with the `details-title` class, which don't exist in the sample you provided. It seems like you are trying to find links located inside divs with the `details-title` class. I believe the easiest way to do this is to search using CSS selectors, which you can do with Beautiful Soup's `.select` method.

Example: `links = soup.select("div.details-title a")`

The `<tag>.<class>` syntax searches for all tags with that class, and elements separated by a space will search for sub-elements of the results before it. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more information.